# Web Forms How to add response cookie for one-time token when navigating to root URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, webforms

I'm going to try and explain the problem as best I can. I have a Web Forms application which requires that a user is able to sign-in to the application using a one-time token passed in as a query parameter in the URL. For example:

`https://\<some endpoint>/Default?token=\<some value>`

I am using this token to create a session server-side and am returning the authorization token in the response as a cookie to be used by the browser on any subsequent requests. I have this working in most cases, with the exception of when the endpoint is the root url (`https://\<my domain>/?token=XXX`). In this case the user just outright fails to get any auth information back.

As far as the code, I am handling the authentication in `Global.asax.cs` in the `Application_AuthenticateRequest`, and I write the cookie with `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(someCookie)`. It looks like `Application_AuthenticateRequest` is being called twice when the user navigates to the root instead of a specific aspx page. This causes the token to fail the second time and cookie is getting "lost", for lack of a better term, between the requests and I'm not sure why. Here is a minimal example of my code and what I am seeing:

In Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    private static HashSet<string> _usedTokens = new HashSet<string>();
    private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        string oneUseToken = httpContext.Request.QueryString["token"];
        string storedCookie = null;

        bool tokenJustAdded = false;
        if (oneUseToken != null && !_usedTokens.Contains(oneUseToken))
        {
            // If the token has not been used, "authenticate" using the token.
            _usedTokens.Add(oneUseToken);

            var cookie = new HttpCookie("authcookie", oneUseToken)
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
            };

            // Add the token as a cookie so that it can be used on subsequent requests.
            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
            tokenJustAdded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // If the token is not valid or doesn't exist, "authenticate" using the cookie.
            if(httpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(k => k == "authcookie") != null)
            {
                storedCookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies["authcookie"].Value;
            }
        }

        // Unrelated code I'm for displaying to the page
        _Default.DisplayText = oneUseToken != null && tokenJustAdded
        ? $"Hello '{oneUseToken}' (Token)"
        : storedCookie != null
            ? $"Hello '{storedCookie}' (Cookie)"
            : "Not Logged In";
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SsoTokenIssueMinimalExample._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>
            <%=DisplayText %>
        </h1>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public static string DisplayText { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here's a visual representation of what's happening:
Full path of an aspx page with token:
[App authenticated with token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo6OF.png)

Cookie should now exist, so if I remove the query param and navigate to the page again the token is correctly pulled from the request cookie:
[App authenticated using stored cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgRsJ.png)

Now if I redo the process using the root URL:
The token fails on the first try:
[Not logged in with the token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfPEz.png)

Cookie should now exist, at least, but when I remove the query param and navigate to the page again the user is still not logged in :( :
[No cookie can be found so user is not authenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqRti.png)

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and how to get this to work?